# when to use lowercase vs uppercase, and when to use plurals

Tags: angularjs, naming-conventions

I still new to programming, but I continue to miss something in the area of when to capitalize vs when to use lowercase.  Additionally, using plurals.  I know this is vague, but for example when working with controllers in a mvc design, I just don't get when I should or can convert capital to lower, or when to use a word as a plural.  Additionally, what if it's a word that doesn't lend itself to just adding a "s", but instead should have "es" or something else.  Should I not use these words.  I'm not entirely sure this question even makes sense, but let me know if anyone has any links discussing some topics along these lines.

Here is some angular running from the controller below.  I was working through an angular tutorial and was attempting to alter the words, but now I can't get it to work.  I assume it has something to do with my conversions.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular/css/cssmain.css">

</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies.cast">
                <td>{{movie.name}}</td>
                <td>{{movie.year}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

main.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('Movies', function() {
    var Movies = {};
    Movies.cast = [
    {
        name: "The Dark Knight",
        year: "2008"
    },
    {
        name: "Pulp Fiction",
        year: "1994"
    },
    {
        name: "Fight Club"
        year: "1999"
    },
    {
        name: "Inception",
        year: "2010"
    }
    ];
    return Movies;
})

function MoviesCtrl($scope, Movies) {
    $scope.movies = Movies;
}
```

Comment: This is highly organization and programmer-specific.  There are general standards and conventions, but every business operates differently.  I think Entity Framework is one of the few areas plurals actually matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uppercase / Lowercase are usually a result of a coding standard that you follow.  A lot of people use the lower first letter, with subsequent words being Capitalized (lowerCase).  My coding standard is first letter of each word is capitalized (UpperCase).  I set classes to be all uppercase with an underscore between words (CLASS_NAME).

The plural form is used when it is appropriate to describe the object you are referencing.  For instance:
Singlar object for the class (STORE).  An array of the class objects would be Stores (plural here to indicate what is contained).

```
var Store = {
    "Name": "Store Name",
    "AddressLines": [
        {
            "Line1": "123 Some Street",
            "Line2": "Unit ABC"
        }
    ],
    "City": "Some Town",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Employees": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "John Doe"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Bill Smith"
        }
    ]
```

Then, in my code, for any loops:

```
<tr ng-repeat="Employee in Store.Employees">
}
```

Comment: There are standard naming conventions, though: constructor functions are CamelCased (with teh first letter uppercase), whereas other functions and variables are camelCased (with the first letter lowercase).

Comment: @JBNizet We use a different coding standard so as to easily tell our modules and code apart from the library or other code being merged/used in the pages.  Using our own style helps to prevent mistaking libraries and our code.  If you are writing libraries or common modules, then definitely use the standards for interoperability and ease of reading/following code for others.